# How can I speed up my MySQL UUID v4 stored function?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, uuid

I'm attempting to write a MySQL stored function to generate v4 UUIDs as described in RFC 4122's section 4.4 ( http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt ). My initial naive effort after a few tweaks is the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UUID_V4()
RETURNS BINARY(16)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    SET @uuid = CONCAT(
        LPAD( HEX( FLOOR( RAND() * 4294967296 ) ), 8, '0' ),
        LPAD( HEX( FLOOR( RAND() * 4294967296 ) ), 8, '0' ),
        LPAD( HEX( FLOOR( RAND() * 4294967296 ) ), 8, '0' ),
        LPAD( HEX( FLOOR( RAND() * 4294967296 ) ), 8, '0' )
    );
    SET @uuid = CONCAT(
        SUBSTR( @uuid FROM 1 FOR 12 ),
        '4',
        SUBSTR( @uuid FROM 14 FOR 3 ),
        SUBSTR( 'ab89' FROM FLOOR( 1 + RAND() * 4 ) FOR 1 ),
        SUBSTR( @uuid FROM 18 )
    );
    RETURN UNHEX(@uuid);
END
```

The above function is quite slow: almost 100 times slower than the built-in `UUID()`, according to MySQL's `BENCHMARK()` feature. Short of writing a UDF using MySQL's C API, are there any improvements I can make here to, say, shave off an order of magnitude from its runtime?

If there is an already existing, well-regarded UUID UDF or stored procedure, I'd be happy to hear about that, too.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but how come you want to create your own function instead of using already mentioned MySQL's UUID() one (I don't know if MySQL's one differs from RFC 4122, so if it does sorry for asking)?

Comment: MySQL's `UUID()` does not generate a uuid according to RFC4122, and the way it generates it breaks statement-based replication.

Comment: Your function would also break statement-based replication. You can avoid that by setting the binlog format to "MIXED" or "ROW" so the replaying of the log won't call the function, but insert the actual row values which makes UUID() viable for use. Also, what guarantee is there that your function won't generate duplicate UUIDs? The only random factor you got is 5 calls to RAND() (which is what makes it slow in the first place). I'd write a UDF for MySQL and implement it that way rather than creating the solution via function, that should yield way better performance.

Comment: Why using UUID in the first place? Perhaps CRC32-based solution suffice?

Comment: Michael J.V.: If you'll add your comment in as an answer, I'll accept it. I think avoiding a UDF outright is going to keep me from getting the speed boost I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8):

I didn't test this for correctness or for performance. It is just the idea of doing one only concatenation in instead of two.

```
create function uuid_v4()
returns binary(16)
begin
    set @h1 = lpad(hex(floor(rand() * 4294967296)), 8, '0');
    set @h2 = lpad(hex(floor(rand() * 4294967296)), 8, '0');
    set @h3 = lpad(hex(floor(rand() * 4294967296)), 8, '0');
    set @h4 = lpad(hex(floor(rand() * 4294967296)), 8, '0');

    set @uuid = concat(
        @h1,
        substr(@h2 from 1 for 4),
        '4',
        substr(@h2 from 6),
        substr('ab89' from floor(1 + rand() * 4) for 1 ),
        substr(@h3 from 2),
        @h4
    );
    return unhex(@uuid);
end
;
```

Also why do you use `READS SQL DATA` in your function?

Comment: re `READS SQL DATA`: I'm currently having to use statement-based replication, and `DETERMINISTIC`, `NO SQL`, or `READS SQL DATA` is necessary to not break it.

Comment: But you know that this statement is not safe to replicate, right?